# Why is Type Annotation Required Here?

Tags: f#

This function has the signature: `(UnionCaseInfo -> bool) -> 'T option`

```
let private findCase<'T> f =
    match FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<'T> |> Array.filter f with
        |[|case|] -> Some (FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case,[||]) :?> 'T)
        |_ -> None
```

This function, which calls the above function, has the signature: `int -> obj`

```
let CreateFromId<'T> id = 
    match findCase (fun case -> case.Tag = id) with
        | Some c -> c
        | None   -> failwith (sprintf "Lookup for union case by \"%d\" failed." id)
```

In the pattern for `CreateFromId`, intellisense shows that `c` is inferred to be of type `obj`, even though it shows the correct signature for `findCase`.  Why does the type seem to have been "lost" in the pattern?

(I can workaround this by specifying the return type of `CreateFromId` to `'T`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the type parameter `'T` is not referenced in the body of the function, so type inference has no way to know your intention was to name `'T` the return type.

So you can either add it in the body as the return type (as you already figured it out) or remove it from the declaration:

```
let CreateFromId id = ...
```

By removing it works because F# does automatic generalization, the only different is it will use an arbitrary name for the type variable, but even if you want to name that type variable 'T what I would do is add it as a return type but no in the declaration between brackets:

```
let CreateFromId id : 'T = ...
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I think I need to have the type parameter because `FSharpType.GetUnionCases` requires it.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `CreateFromId` was inferred to by `int -> obj` because there's nothing "linking" the two `'T` type arguments on your functions.

`findCase` is properly generic over `'T`, but `CreateFromId` is only declared to be generic, and the generic type argument is never used.

Annotating the function with the desired type is good enough to make the types line up. You can also call `findCase` explicitly providing the type:

```
let CreateFromId<'T> id = 
    match findCase<'T> (fun case -> case.Tag = id) with
    | Some c -> c
    | None   -> failwith (sprintf "Lookup for union case by \"%d\" failed." id)
```

Or as the other answer suggests, just drop the `'T` from `CreateFromId` and let type inference do its thing.